# Power BI slicer to filter within from-to columns limit

Tags: powerbi, date-range, slicers

Good morning.

I have a table with date from and to columns.

I have a slicer where user can select date interval.

How can I filter the table to show those records where
-either start date or end date (or both) is within slicer intervall?

Thanks in advance.